# Why we need 'namespace scope' concept? - in C++

Tags: c++

I learned that in namespace "name decoration(mangling)" takes place so that it can be differentiated from other same identifiers which is in different namespace.
[Wiki: Name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

If then, Why "namespace scope" exists? I thought just 'name decoration' can solve all problem about name conflicting.
Because in C, the reason for name conflicting is eventually that "different entities have same identifier".
**Name decoration can make names(identifiers) different from each other internally, so I think name decoration is what all we need.**

Then, why C++ use 'namespace scope' concept? Just for to use unqualified name in namespace scope? I want to know if there is any reason.

Comment: The term "namespace scope" has a very specific meaning in C++, and it has little to do with the concept of named namespaces or name mangling. A namespace scope is any scope that is not a block scope, a function parameter scope, an enumeration scope, a class scope, or a template parameter scope. It isn't quite clear how you plan to do without namespace scope. What are the exact rules? Can you show a hypothetical code example that would compile under your proposed rules?

Comment: "Name decoration/mangling" is an implementation technique, not a language feature. You won't find any such terms in the requirements in the C++ standard.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  I wanted to know the relationship between namespace and namespace scope.. but thanks to your answer, I find out that there is no big relationship.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces scope is very useful in programming for the following reasons:

1. Avoids name collisions between functions/classes, eg., Suppose you have two functions of same name but in different namespace scope (`foo::func()` and `bar::func()`)
2. Can be used for managing similar functions inside it, eg., `sin()`, `cos()` and `sqrt()` function *could be under namespace `Math`.*
3. Avoids confusion between classes for an example suppose there's two classes named `lexer`, but in different namespace scope like `json::lexer` and `xml::lexer`. Now, it gives clear understanding to the programmer to choose between them according to their language i.e, `xml` or `json`.

An everyday example of namespace could be `std`, stands for `standard`, it contains every single functions and classes defined in the standard library, it also includes `STL` classes like `std::vector`, `std::map` and `std::string`.

*NOTE: There's no concept of namespace scope in `C`.*

Answer (score 1):

Namespace scope is a concept in the programming language that the developer sees, allowing them to organise their code effectively and understand it better. Name mangling is something the compiler does under the hood in order to implement namespaces (including namespace scope) in a way the linker can understand. In normal circumstances the developer doesn't need to think about name mangling, although its useful to know how it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm still curious about namespace scope. I don't think "just namespace scope" can avoid name conflicts... e.g. If file a.cpp has a definition `int a=3;` at file scope, and file b.cpp had a definition `int a=5;` at file scope, then this two definitions are in different scope. but they conflicts because both are external linkage.